# Adding Links to TopNavigation via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am receiving the following error when attempting to add a Link to the Top Navigation Bar.

"Exception calling "AddAsLast" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"

Here is the code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $url.Url;

$newLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -ArgumentList  @($web.Title, $web.Url);  

$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast($newLink);
$web.Update();
```

looking for some reasons and work arounds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine, I run the exact same code and it works without a  problem.

Some things to look at:

- Does your account have the right level of access? I know, probably silly question, but just checking
- What does the ULS log say when you're running this command?
- Try wrapping in an SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges({}) statement
- Try some more simple cases (get the web then update it immediately without adding anything to the navigation bar to verify navigation is part of the problem)

Comment: Thanks for checking this for me.  The trick for me was to run my powershell window using an account capable of adding top nav links

Answer (score 1):

You had .url in the `Get-SPWeb` variable at the beginning of the script.  This works

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $url

$newLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -ArgumentList  @($web.Title, $web.Url);  

$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast($newLink);
$web.Update();
```

Comment: If you want to use external URLs, use $TRUE as third parameter.