# Add Link TopNavigationBar to a publishing site by powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, hyperlink, quick-launch, top-link-bar

I have a site collection with some sites (**Publishing theme**).
I need to add some links to the *top navigation bar* and the *quick launch* by *Powershell*.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://myurl"
$newLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -ArgumentList  @("test", "http://www.google.com");  
$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast($newLink);
$web.Update();
```

I tried this code,it runs fine, but I can not see the new link.
If I try to add a new link from the UI, I can not see it in the `$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar` object.
It is working with an other template (ex team site)

Comment: Isn't the topbar a termset in publishing site?

Comment: I don't know, what do you mean?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.taxonomynavigation_members.aspx

Comment: Maybe it is hidden by the Masterpage. Check the CSS for "ms-breadcrumb-top"

Comment: Thanks, but I can not see them in the object so I do not think that is just a visualization problem :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Links to TopNavigation via Powershell](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/adding-links-to-topnavigation-via-powershell)

Comment: I think we had that before: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/adding-links-to-topnavigation-via-powershell

Comment: Thanks, but no. The problem is with the publishing template, a term set must be used

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the SharePoint 2013 Taxonomy.
These are the steps:
- Create a Term Set

- Setting site nav to use taxonomy

Tutorial:
[SharePoint 2013 Taxonomy](http://anujabhojani.blogspot.it/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-taxonomy-import-using.html)

NB: I changed the Get-date format, this works for me `$date = Get-Date -Format s`